# GitVersion appending '-pullrequest1089-0002' to build number

Tags: azure-devops, gitversion

I have a build pipeline set up on Azure Devops for building a Nuget Package.

So far I have been using only the master branch, after each push to the master branch and then manually triggering the build, the build number got correctly incremented.

Yesterday I decided to create a feature branch, implemented some changes and created a PR. After it got approved and merged into master I manually trigger a new build but this time the build version contains the '-pullrequest1089-0002' string as well. This means that this new version is not available in NuGet package manager for me to install.

[image]

I need to somehow configure this so this won't get appended.

This is how my gitversion.yml file looks like:

```
mode: MainLine
next-version: 1.0.0
```

Comment: How's your pipeline generating versions? Is it using `Nerdbank.GitVersioning` or something? Fwiw your new package probably is available in NuGet package manager, but you'll need to tick the box to include pre-release versions in order to see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for trying to help. I was not allowed to use pre-release packages. My issue turned out to be rooted in not having enabled CI/CD.

After I turned that option on, it's working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For this issue , agree with **rbennett485** , since the format `1.0.32-xxx` is the format of pre-release nuget packages. To get it to display in nuget package manager, you just need to enable the Include prerelease checkbox.

You can compare the two pictures below to see the difference:

[image]

[image]